# Ordered merge problems

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge

I've got a little problem with my program and I can't solve what's wrong. Basically, there are two arrays sorted in ascending order and I have to merge them into one.

I expect the output to be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

But it is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 0
```

What am I doing wrong, that the last value in the output isn't 14? I think that the solution to this will be very simple, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){

 int arrA[]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13};
 int arrB[]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14};
 int arrC[sizeof(arrA)/sizeof(int)+sizeof(arrB)/sizeof(int)];

 int sizeA=sizeof(arrA)/sizeof(int);
 int sizeB=sizeof(arrB)/sizeof(int);
 int sizeC=sizeof(arrC)/sizeof(int);

 for (int i=0;i<sizeA;){
    for (int j=0;j<sizeB;){
        if (arrA[i]<=arrB[j]){
            arrC[i+j]=arrA[i++];
        }
        else{
            arrC[i+j]=arrB[j++];
        }
    }
 }

for (int i=0; i<sizeC; i++){
    cout << arrC[i] << " ";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you never get to the point where You assign value to arrC[13] which is the last 14 element. In last iteration for your outer loop i==6 and the same for the inner loop. So you end when i+j is equal to 12.

Comment: So I have to change the loops. Thanks for help ;)